# SEVERE: null<br> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller, syntax-error, dao

This is my first time posting here.

So, I've been having this error over and over now on my netbeans project and I don't know the reason.
It says that my SQL Syntax is wrong, but there's no way though. Because I copied it from my other java code in the same project (basically for a template) which WORKS just fine. I even tested it by copying the code to a new java file, changed it according to what I needed, and it works.

Here's what I've tried: re-typing all the code for this file manually, but still didn't work. Tried changing the SQL Syntax from using the table "order" to the table "produk", then it works, but when changing back it gives the same error message again. Maybe there's something wrong with the table? So I tried re-creating the table in the database, but nope still error. I've tried checking it by comparing to other similar codes in the project too.

Here's the code:

```
package DAO;

import Koneksi.Database;
import Model.varOrder;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DAO_Order implements DAO_Interface<varOrder>{
Connection connection;

public DAO_Order(){
    connection = Database.KoneksiDB();
}

// Deklarasi SQL Statement
String INSERT = "INSERT INTO order(IDO, Nama, Jenis, Kuantitas) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
String UPDATE = "UPDATE order set Nama=?, Jenis=?, Kuantitas=? WHERE IDO=?";
String DELETE = "DELETE FROM order WHERE IDO=?";
String SELECT = "SELECT * FROM order";
String CARI = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE IDO=?";

@Override
public void insert(varOrder Object) {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try{
        st = connection.prepareStatement(CARI);
        st.setString(1, Object.getvIDO());
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data sudah pernah di simpan.");
        } else{
            st = null;
            st = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT);
            st.setString(1, Object.getvIDO());
            st.setString(2, Object.getvNama());
            st.setString(3, Object.getvJenis());
            st.setString(4, Object.getvKuantitas());
            st.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data berhasil di simpan.");
        }
        st.close();
    }   catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(DAO_Order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void update(varOrder Object) {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try{
        st = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE);
        st.setString(1, Object.getvNama());
        st.setString(2, Object.getvJenis());
        st.setString(3, Object.getvKuantitas());
        st.setString(4, Object.getvIDO());
        st.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data berhasil di update.");
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO_Order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}

@Override
public void delete(String IDO) {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try{
        st = connection.prepareStatement(DELETE);
        st.setString(1, IDO);
        st.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data berhasil di hapus.");
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO_Order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public List<varOrder> getAll() {
    List<varOrder> list = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try{
        st = null;
        list = new ArrayList<varOrder>();
        st = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            varOrder objOrd = new varOrder();
            objOrd.setvIDO(rs.getString("IDO"));
            objOrd.setvNama(rs.getString("Nama"));
            objOrd.setvJenis(rs.getString("Jenis"));
            objOrd.setvKuantitas(rs.getString("Kuantitas"));
            list.add(objOrd);
        }
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO_Order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list;
}

@Override
public List<varOrder> getCari(String key) {
    List<varOrder> list = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try{
        st = null;
        list = new ArrayList<varOrder>();
        st = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT);
        st.setString(1, "%"+key+"%");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            varOrder objOrd = new varOrder();
            objOrd.setvIDO(rs.getString("IDO"));
            objOrd.setvNama(rs.getString("Nama"));
            objOrd.setvJenis(rs.getString("Jenis"));
            objOrd.setvKuantitas(rs.getString("Kuantitas"));
            list.add(objOrd);
        }
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO_Order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

And Here's the error message:

```
run:
Nov 11, 2020 2:50:22 PM DAO.DAO_Order getAll
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at DAO.DAO_Order.getAll(DAO_Order.java:103)
    at Controller.Controller_Order.<init>(Controller_Order.java:32)
    at View.FrmOrder.<init>(FrmOrder.java:26)
    at View.MenuMinimarket.mnuOrderActionPerformed(MenuMinimarket.java:150)
    at View.MenuMinimarket.access$200(MenuMinimarket.java:13)
    at View.MenuMinimarket$3.actionPerformed(MenuMinimarket.java:94)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:842)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:886)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Sorry for the grammar and also the long post! Thank you.

Comment: Surround `order` with backticks: `\`order\``.

Comment: I just tried that but it still gives me the same error. But it works now after I changed the table name instead. From "order" to "orders". Thank you.

Comment: Whoops sorry, nevermind what I said about the backticks, I think it would work. I guess it didn't work for me before was because I thought single quotes and backticks are the same

Answer (score 0):

`Order` is a keyword in SQL. If you want your table to be called "order", you should escape it:

```
INSERT INTO `order`(IDO, Nama, Jenis, Kuantitas) VALUES(?,?,?,?);
UPDATE `order` set Nama=?, Jenis=?, Kuantitas=? WHERE IDO=?;
DELETE FROM `order` WHERE IDO=?
SELECT * FROM `order`;
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE IDO=?
```

Another option is to call your table `orders`, not `order`

Comment: Oh so that's why! I feel dumb now hahaha. OK. I juts tried using ' but still gives the same error dunno why. So I changed the table name instead and it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try a single quote (') or a backtick (`)?

Comment: I see. It was a single quote that I tried, I didn't know a backtick is different. Thank you